# Correct position of edge labels in a graph plot using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a piece of code to draw a graph. For this I am reading some files to get the nodes and the weights.

```
plt.title('Grafo Completo Github')
pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True, node_color="skyblue", font_size=8)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos=pos, edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(g, 'weight'), label_pos=1,  rotate=False, font_size=8)
plt.savefig("grafo_github.jpg")
plt.show()
```

But, this produces the image below. How can I correct the positions of edge labels?
Edge Labels in wrong position:
[image: Edge Labels in wrong position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real mistake seems to be the value of the attribute `label_pos`.
From [the docs of `draw_networkx_edge_labels`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html):

> label_pos (float) – Position of edge label along edge (0=head, 0.5=center, 1=tail)

By using `label_pos=1` the labels were appearing behind the nodes since their position is also on 'the edge tail'.
Changing this value to `0.5` should solve the issue:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(T, pos, edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(T, 'weight'), label_pos=0.5, rotate=False, font_size=8)
```

Or, since `0.5` is default, simply remove it.

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_color="skyblue", font_size=8)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(T, pos, edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(T, 'weight'), rotate=False, font_size=8)
```

Comment: I tried that, but now the graph doesn´t show the edge labels :(

Comment: See if changing `label_pos=1` to `label_pos=0.5` solves it

Answer (score 1):

to label the edges correctly,
include pos=pos parameter in both  draw(  and draw_networkx_edge_labels(